# How can a flip flop alternate between two clocks, turning one off and the other on and repeating?

Tags: timer, flipflop, 555

I am just experimenting with flip flops and am pretty confused about alternating between two clocks. Right, so I want a pulse to be sent to a flip flop first after 18 seconds and then after 2 seconds and then again after 18 seconds.

For this purpose, I have made two 555 timer ICs which generate 18s and 2s pulses respectively. What I have been struggling to do is to, after the 18s timer IC generates a pulse, activate the 2s timer IC and deactivate the 18s timer IC and after the 2s timer IC generates the pulse, I would like to deactivate it and activate the 18s timer IC.

What I want? I want the flip flop to get a pulse after 18seconds, then after 2 seconds, then after 18 seconds and then 2 seconds and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Safely switching between two asynchronous clocks is a complex process. I think it would be easier if you use a 2 sec clock and add a circuit which makes from that a pulse after 9, 1 and 9 'clock' pulses.

Comment: Your requirements are hidden by the attempt to explain a possible solution. Forget any possible solution and state what you require and not what you think might work.

Comment: @oldfart I am sorry, I couldn't quite understand that. Can you please rephrase it. I'll be much obliged.

Comment: @ParkerQueen The clocks are not linked together, so they will drift apart and bear. Think about direction indicators on two cars. The suggestion is just to have \$one\$ clock, and then have a counter which gives out a pulse every 1 then 9 pulses from this single clock.

Comment: @awjlogan Thanks a ton, that really is a great way to do it. However, the question I presented was meant to be generic. What if I want 17 and then 3 sec pulse alternations? Any suggestion for that?

Comment: @ParkerQueen easiest (and best!) solution is to just use the lowest common denominator of your two durations. 17 and 3 are both prime, you'd have a 1 Hz clock and then trigger on 3 then 17. Actually quite a fun exercise in digital design :) Basically you generally want only a single clock in your circuit (for quite a few reasons beyond this example).

Comment: @awjlogan HELL YEA! Been trying to figure this out all day. One last thing though, can you give me a little hint about such a counter circuit? Just the gist of it? And if you can make this an answer then I'll be happy to accept it as the right one.

Comment: @ParkerQueen Don't have time for a full answer just now, but have look at the 4017 IC. It counts up when a pulse is applied, and you just need to work out how to clear it one the times you want. If time, I will try and answer soon. Good luck :)

Comment: @ParkerQueen Very off topic, but your profile text is really humorous - I love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the most simple way to produce the clocking signal you need is to produce a single clock \$Q\$ with a period of 20ms and a 90% duty cycle: by inverting such clock (for example by using a NOT gate or a single fast transistor inverter) you will get another clock  \$\overline{Q}\$ with the same period but with a 10% duty cycle. Each of this waveform is shown below:

[image]

Then, the original clock signal will provide the 18ms pulse, while the inverted one will provide the 2ms, for example by ORing the outputs of the following simple RCD trigger circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEr1yA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By calling \$t_1\$ the trigger generated by feeding \$Q\$ to the input the of the above circuit and \$t_2\$ the one generated by \$\overline{Q}\$, these signals have waveforms similar to the following ones:

[image]

And ORing the two triggers you'll get the following composite one:

[image]

**A few notes**

1. You can use one 555 to generate \$Q\$ and then inverting its output: however the simplest way is perhaps to generate both \$Q\$ and \$\overline{Q}\$ by a single, properly designed, [astable multivibrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator#Astable_multivibrator).
2. The RCD trigger circuit show above is simply an analog *differentiator*: \$R\$ and \$C\$ control the duration of the trigger pulse, while \$D\$ rules out the negative pulse which would otherwise appear during the falling of the input squared wave signal.
3. This is an hybrid analog/digital solution to your problem: if you need to work with only logic gates, perhaps the solution to which awjlogan alludes is the best.